# Redirect from doi.org to onlinelibrary.wiley.com fails

Tags: python, python-requests

If I visit `https://doi.org/10.1002/jccs.200600142` with my browser, everything is fine. But both requests fail:

```bash
python -c "import requests; print(requests.head('https://doi.org/10.1002/jccs.200600142', allow_redirects=True))"

<Response [403]>
```

I also tried accepting cookies and changing the user-agent, which also did not help:

```py
import requests
with requests.Session() as s:
    print(s.get('https://doi.org/10.1002/jccs.200600142', allow_redirects=True, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/114.0'}))

<Response [403]>
```

Does someone know what `requests` does differently than Firefox? Or should I include more headers?